# The opposite of damaged

Tags: word-request

[image: two grates]

In this picture there are two **grates**, which is the name I use for them, I call the bottom one, **the damaged grate**, what to call the top one, which is not damaged and intact?

Answer (score 3):

You already said it: "intact." Other alternatives include "mint condition," "brand new" (or "like new" if it isn't actually new, just in good condition), or just plain undamaged.

Comment: Unmarred, pristine, in good shape possibly.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the word "untarnished" as well depending on the circumstance, maybe not necessarily in this case though.

Untarnished meaning not dulled, or damaged.